# Select object from listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have a Activity in a project which holds a list of objects of type X. This objects are displayed in a listview on their name. When I click an item in the list I want to continue with the chosen object and display its details. Now, passing arguments in Android through Activities doesn't seem so handy... So what is the usual way to do this kind of thing in android? Currently I see this option:
I start a new Activity and pass the ID with a bundle. Then fetch the object again from the database.

Comment: sure, that is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

the way I do it is to put the JSON-serialized object into a `Bundle` (putString) and pass this through the `Intent` I'm using to start the `Activity` that will show the single item in detail view.

EDIT: the fact that the JSON-string is a very handy thing to store in the savedInstanceState makes this an even more attractive solution IMO

Comment: But thats exactly what I didn't want to do. Because it seems bad programming practice and seems to slow down the application. Also an object can't always be made serializable isn't it? What if one day I decide to include something in my object which isn't serializable?

Comment: I'm talking about JSON-serializing, which I thought I'd edited into the answer... but I'd rather do that than re-query the database. also, it's a very handy string to store in savedInstanceState.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. Make your object implement Serializable and share it via intent
2. Pass the ID and retrieve it
3. Use a singleton class with static fields to share between classes
4. Use GlobalState (no experience with this one, but I know it's possible)
5. Use SharedPreferences (although this is close to using the db)

Comment: #3 from this list is KIND OF what I practice and what I recommend. actually I use JSON to do my serialization rather than implementing `Serializable`

Comment: Second that. I should've ordered them by most advised :p /meh

Comment: I know .. I'm just being a bit lazy xD

Comment: UPDATE: edited to what I think are the most advised practices :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the selected item details on a new activity, in the main activity you should use an Intent, for example:

```
Intent intentNew = new Intent(<YourActivity>.this, <NewActivity>.class);
        intentNew.putExtra("ItemDetails", vector);  //put an array or whatever you want, filled with item details
        startActivityForResult(intentNew,1);
```

In the NewActivity, you should do:

```
 double[] vector= (double[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ItemDetails");
```